# std::string vs string literal for functions

Tags: c++, string, stdstring, string-literals

I was wondering, I normally use std::string for my code, but when you are passing a string in a parameter for a simply comparison, is it better to just use a literal?

Consider this function:

```
bool Message::hasTag(string tag)
{
    for(Uint tagIndex = 0; tagIndex < m_tags.size();tagIndex++)
    {
        if(m_tags[tagIndex] == tag)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Despite the fact that the property it is making a comparison with is a vector, and whatever uses this function will probably pass strings to it, would it still be better to use a const char* to avoid creating a new string that will be used like a string literal anyway?

Comment: Parameters of class/struct type should always be passed by reference (probably const reference) unless you have a specific reason otherwise.

Comment: You should not be "using namespace std;" in your code. There will be trouble, I promise.

Comment: @amro using namespace std; is perfectly OK in source files, just not in headers.

Comment: @amro: You should only avoid importing *any* namespace (not just `std`) within header files. You're free to do whatever you want inside your `.cpp` files. So always say `std::string` in your header files, but your .cpp files often (usually?) are perfectly fine with a `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Sooner or later, you'll run into a collision and end up with implementation files that have using namespace std; and files that don't. I guess it's up to you if you want to deal with that, but I find it's better to avoid getting used to using namespace std; entirely.

Comment: @neil - I have to wonder why you'd say that since you don't justify the statement.  Performance wise it's false in a great many cases.

Comment: @Noah which of my comments are you responding to?

Comment: @Noah So you are suggesting value parameters are more efficient than  reference ones? Some evidence for this would be a good idea, possibly as an answer to this question.

Comment: @Neil - yes, indeed there are cases when values will be faster than references.  One should check with a profiler before deciding that one is better than the other for any given situation.  Before checking with a profiler one is only doing guess based micro-optimizations.  There are of course times when you can know that copying will be slow but in cases of small objects, like string, you really don't unless you've tested it.

Comment: @Noah Like most of your posts - utter crap. Do you really use a profiler to decide on the type of every function parameter? No, of course you don't. I won't be responding to any of your future posts here. Goodbye.

Comment: @Neil - what an interesting reply to a request that you clarify your position.  If you want your blanket statements taken on faith rather than debated then perhaps you should quit the sciences and go start a religion.  I have noticed that you're mostly FOS but I didn't realize how childish you were until now.

Comment: And BTW, you're right.  I rarely, if ever, decide which type to use as a parameter based on profiling results.  Parameter types have simply never been the bottleneck.  In a situation where it mattered though I would certainly prefer to base my decision on tested fact rather than mere guesswork and assumption.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to use classes, the best approach here is a const reference:

```
bool Message::hasTag(const string& tag);
```

That way, redudant copying can be minimized and it's made clear that the method doesn't intend to modify the argument. I *think* a clever compiler can emit pretty good code for the case when this is called with a string literal.

Passing a character pointer requires you to use `strcmp()` to compare, since if you start comparing pointers directly using `==`, there will be ... trouble.

Comment: It will have to construct a string object, no matter how clever the compiler is.

Comment: Neil what do you mean by having to construct a string object? Doesn't the compiler just "exchange" the "&" with "*" and properly interpret any dereferencing syntax?

Comment: @ctinnist: If you're passing a reference (or a pointer) to a `string` object, you still have to have a `string` object at some point.

Comment: @Frerich: well, yes, otherwise you'll need to have a char* array somewhere... the OP is concerned about implicit copies when passing strings to functions, not the object creation itself.

Comment: `Passing a character pointer requires you to use strcmp()`: comparing two `std::strings` has to compare both strings character by character as well, so passing a `std::string` doesn't offer any improvement there.

Comment: @Frerich: of course there is an improvement, m_tags[tagIndex] == tag is easier to read (shorter) than strcmp(m_tags[tagIndex], tag) == 0. I'm not saying there's a *performance* improvement, I never tried to imply that all characters don't have to be inspected.

Comment: @unwind: `m_tags[tagIndex]` apparently already contains strings, judging from the code in the question. Hence, you don't need `strcmp` at all. Just continue using `m_tags[tagIndex] == tag` (using the `const char *` overload of the comparison operator).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: it depends.

Long answer: `std::string` is highly useful because it provides a lot of utility functions for strings (searching for substrings, extracting substrings, concatenating strings etc.). It also manages the memory for you, so the ownership of the string cannot be confused.

In your case, you don't need either. You just need to know whether any of the objects in `m_tags` matches the given string. So for your case, writing the function using a `const char *s` is perfectly sufficient.

However, as a foot note: you almost always want to prefer `std::string` over `(const) char *` when talking about *return values*. That's because C strings have no ownership semantics at all, so a function returning a `const char *` needs to be documented very carefully, explaining who owns the pointed to memory (caller or callee) and, in case the callee gets it, how to free it (`delete[]`, `delete`, `free`, something else).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be enough to pass an reference rather than value of `string`. I mean:

```
bool Message::hasTag(const string& tag)
```

That would copy only the reference to the original `string` value. Which must be created somwhere anyway, but outside of the function. This function would not copy its parameter whatsoever.

Since `m_tags` is a vector of strings anyway (I suppose), `const string&` parameter would be better idea.